# does s3cmd put command overwrite files?

Tags: backup, cloud-storage, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I am trying to write a script that will automatically backup a drive I have to amazon s3. I have downloaded `s3cmd` and I am wondering what the `put` command does...

It seems to me like it uploads the files every time, overwriting them. Is that what it does or not?

I am looking for something like `rsync -av --delete` so that it will only do something if there is a change...

What can I do?

Comment: Use `sync` for backup. See [Data backup using AWS S3cmd: a simple and effective solution](http://cloudacademy.com/blog/data-backup-s3cmd/)